# Deformation vs Strong Deformation Retract

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

When I think of deformation retracts visually, I can only visualize strong deformation retracts. Can someone give a simple, easy to visualize example of a subset that is a deformation retract, but not a strong deformation retract?

Comment: The same example is discussed in more detail in [this PDF](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/math432/Solution_1.pdf); it’s the last problem in the PDF.